# CountDownTimer switch background of RelativeLayouts (1&2)

Tags: android, background-image, android-relativelayout, drawable, countdowntimer

I trying to run a timer to switch Backgrounds of two relative layouts in loop if user set or unset it while app is running.
Not enough I tried to work with `drawable_image.setAlpha(x)` to let the Background vanish slowly while the relative layout 2 behind has an other image (afterwords switch position).

My method `private void switchBackground(){}` do it right well. BUT it is too much work for the device and I lose a lot of frames (15-39) so that the "slow vanish" by `.setAlph(x)` sometimes totally fail and not working (the pics switch just by time, like the onTick() method do not exists anymore).

I think one reason for this is the countDownTimer itself and a second that the method is (should) running in the main Activity Class. May be the third reason is the problem that I choose "setBackground" of relative Layouts instead of image showing stuff?!

I tried adding a new Class to do the "switchBackground .."- method outside, but this failed cause of "nullpointerexception" and "non-static / static" problems.

Which classes and methods would be better, so as not to lose too much frames / memory.

```
    //"/---/" short up stuff which isn't important, but still much do there
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   //class value
   //private static final String TAG = "App";
   private RelativeLayout layout_behind;
   private RelativeLayout layout_front;
   private CountDownTimer myCountdown;
   private final int[][] matrix = new int[9][9];
   private EditText sumNum;
   private MediaPlayer music;
   private SoundPool multiTon;
   private int whoopId;
   private int failId;
   private int winId;
   private boolean soundOn =WelcomeScreen.soundCheck;
    //class MathThing, Welcome_Screen exists too
   private final int[][] detected = MathThing.detected; 
   private final ArrayList<int[][]> returnArr = new ArrayList<>();
   private int switch_draw=0;
   private boolean switchDraw;
   private Drawable image_2;
   private Drawable image_1;
   private Drawable image_3;

   @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  //Music
    multiTon = new SoundPool(1,AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,0);
    whoopId = multiTon.load(this, R.raw.whoop,1);
    failId = multiTon.load(this, R.raw.fail, 1);
    winId = multiTon.load(this, R.raw.win,1);
    music = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.backgroundmusic);
  if(WelcomeScreen.musicCheck) {
      music.setVolume(1, 1);
      music.setLooping(true);
      music.start();
  }

  //create/initialize some stuff and initialize layouts and images
  hideAndCreate();

  //switch Background
 switchBackground(); switchDraw=true;

}
@Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
   return true;
 }
  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
   // . . . settings in Toolbar
   int id = item.getItemId();
        switch(id){   
      case R.id.bla:  //just cut some here to do it shorter
   break;// /.../
  }
  return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }

 private void hideAndCreate(){
   // /----/ create a lot of edittexts / textviews/ buttons 
   //initialize layouts / images
 }

protected void onPause(){
  super.onPause();
  if(switchDraw){
  myCountdown.cancel();}
  music.release();
  finish();
    }
  //method with CountDownTimer
  private void switchBackground(){
  //Layout Background
  switch_draw=0;
  layout_behind.setBackground(image_2);
  int duration=15000;
  int tick=250;
  myCountdown = new CountDownTimer(duration, tick){
    int a = 255;
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        if(switch_draw==0){
            image_1.setAlpha(a);
            layout_front.setBackground(image_1);
            if(a>=4){a=a-4;}
        }else if(switch_draw==1){
            image_2.setAlpha(a);
            layout_front.setBackground(image_2);
            if(a>=4){a=a-4;}
        }else{
            image_3.setAlpha(a);
            layout_front.setBackground(image_3);
            if(a>=4){a=a-4;}
        }
    }

    public void onFinish() {
        if(switch_draw==0){
            image_2.setAlpha(255);
            layout_front.setBackground(image_2);
            image_3.setAlpha(255);
            layout_behind.setBackground(image_3);
            switch_draw=1;
        }else if(switch_draw==1){
            image_3.setAlpha(255);
            layout_front.setBackground(image_3);
            image_1.setAlpha(255);
            layout_behind.setBackground(image_1);
            switch_draw=2;
        }else{
            image_1.setAlpha(255);
            layout_front.setBackground(image_1);
            image_2.setAlpha(255);
            layout_behind.setBackground(image_2);
            switch_draw=0;
        }
         a=255;
         start();//loop stuff
      }
   }.start();
  }

   public void StartOnClick(View v){
    //do something when the button is clicked

   if(v.getId()==R.id.button1){
    /---/   

    }else if(v.getId()==R.id.button2){
    /---/

   }else if(v.getId()==R.id.buttonw1){
       /---/

   }else if(v.getId()==R.id.buttonw2){
        /---/               

    }else if(v.getId()==R.id.buttonw3){
    /---/
   }
  }
     private void setReset(){
    /---/ //clear all
  }

 private void againRestart(){
       /---/ //reset entries only
  }

  //         main Method

 private void numInput(){
   int[][]found;
   int n = 81;
   int mini=1;

  while(mini==1 && n>0){

    TextView text;
    Button but1;
    int[][]nul=new int[2][81];
    int[][]value=new int[3][81];
    int i=-1;
    int j=-1;
    int a=0;
    int b=0;
    for(int idN=0; idN<81; idN++) {
        int iDn=idN +1;
        String editTextId = "editText" + iDn;
        int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(editTextId, "id",
                    getPackageName());
        sumNum=((EditText)findViewById(resID) );

        if(idN%9 == 0){
            i=i+1;
            j=0;

        }else{
            j=j+1;
     }if(!TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(sumNum.getText()) ||
        sumNum.getText   ().toString().equals("0") ){
            sumNum.setText("");
        }
        if(sumNum.getText().toString().trim().length()==0){       
            matrix[i][j]= 0;
            nul[0][a]=i;
            nul[1][a]=j;
            a=a+1;
        }else {
           matrix[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(sumNum.getText().toString());
            value[0][b]=i;
            value[1][b]=j;
            value[2][b]=matrix[i][j];
            b=b+1;
        }
    }
//copy array
    int[][]nuL=new int[2][a];
    int[][]val=new int[3][b];
    for(int u=0;u<b;u++){
        val[0][u]=value[0][u];
        val[1][u]=value[1][u];
        val[2][u]=value[2][u];
    }
    for(int nu=0;nu<a;nu++){
        nuL[0][nu]=nul[0][nu];
        nuL[1][nu]=nul[1][nu];
    }


    n = nuL[0].length;

    // matrix check
if(MathThing.matrixIsGood(val) && n>0){

//method matrixCheck
    found = MathThing.matrixCheck(matrix, nuL);


//cut method
    found = MathThing.zeroCut(found, n);

  // method
    int[] min = MathThing.minSearch(found);
    mini = min[0];          

    if(min[0]==1 && n>0) {
               /---/               
    }else if(min[0]==2 && n>0 ){
       /---/
    }else if(min[0]>2 && n>0 || n==81){
      /---/
    }else if(min[0]==0 && n>0) {
       /---/

    }}else if(n!=0){
    /---/             
}
if(n==0){
    /---/
    }         
}
}
```

Comment: you should you Handle.post(Runable unable) to switch the background instead of write the code in main thread

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer!

Ok, I will try it with a Handler solution, but I still need to "write" it in the main-activity-class?
Cause of the Relative-Layout and Drawable (getDrawable) static / non static problems?!

Comment: post your code, it will help me easier to help

Comment: Hey, I found something interesting: If I add " edit.setText(String.format("Tick %d", millisUntilFinished / 1000));  " to my switchBackground() method in the CountDownTimer in onTick() method to show each second as an editText- String, so its working better, reduce the "switch" to 2 images and its working to 95% fine. May be this extra "work" in onTick() give that method more time to my stuff below (not ignore it).